# Find string in txt file using a list c#

Tags: c#, string, list

I am trying to find out if a `.txt` file contains words stored in a list named `Abreviated`. This list is filled by reading values from a `csv` file as shown below;

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\textwords.csv");
string TxtWrd = sr.ReadLine();
while ((TxtWrd = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Words = TxtWrd.Split(Seperators, StringSplitOptions.None);
            Abreviated.Add(Words[0]);
            Expanded.Add(Words[1]);
        }
```

I would like to use this list to check if a `.txt` file contains any of the words in the list. The `.txt` file is being read using a `streamreader` and is stored as a string `FileContent`. the code i have to try and find the matches is below;

```
if (FC.Contains(Abreviated.ToString()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Match found");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Match");

        }
```

This will always return the else statement even though one of the words is in the text file.

any advice on  how to get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's input (of csv file)?

Comment: What is `Abreviated`? If that is a `List<string>`, then what do you think `Abreviated.ToString()` is? Hint: it is _not_ a string containing all of the items in the list...

Comment: By the way, are you skipping the first line of your file on purpose?

Comment: @MaciejLos the CSV file contains two columns of words, column 1 is the abbreviated e.g. "wuu2" and the second column is the full version e.g. "What you up to". hope this helps

Comment: @oerkelens yes the firs line contains the column headers, `Abreviated` is a list I would believe its an array?

Comment: Seems, you need a `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to learn [How To Debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Indeed, debug and see what `List<string>.ToString()` gives you. As I hinted, it is _not_ what you think it is, and it is _not_ useful for your purpose. Another hint: you could loop over one list and check if the entry is in the other list.

Comment: also - use csvhelper library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `key-value pair` data structure for storing abbreviated word and respective full word as key-value pair. In C#, `Dictionary` has generic implementation for storing key value pair.

I've refactored your code which makes easy to reuse.

```
internal class FileParser
{
    internal Dictionary<string, string> WordDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private string _filePath;
    private char Seperators => ',';
    internal FileParser(string filePath)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
    }

    internal void Parse()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_filePath);
        string TxtWrd = sr.ReadLine();
        while ((TxtWrd = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var words = TxtWrd.Split(Seperators, StringSplitOptions.None);
            //WordDictionary.TryAdd(Words[0], Words[1]); // available in .NET corefx https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1942
            if (!WordDictionary.ContainsKey(words[0]))
                WordDictionary.Add(words[0], words[1]);
        }
    }

    internal bool IsWordAvailable(string word)
    {
        return WordDictionary.ContainsKey(word);
    }
}
```

Now, you can reuse above class within your assembly like in following way :

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fileParser = new FileParser(@"C:\textwords.csv");
            if(fileParser.IsWordAvailable("abc"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Match found");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Match");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  i have had a look at this and would `internal class FileParser` be a seperate class or contained within the main program? also i am getting errors with `StringSplitOptions` and `Tryadd` but VS isnt being any use with why its flagging this up.

Comment: @bdg : FileParser should be separate class for the purpose of reusability.  What type of `Seperators` are you using because based on its type, different `Split` overloaded method are available. About `TryAdd`, it's added .NET coreFx. I'll add another alternative for adding key-value.

Comment: I've updated `FileParser` implementation

Comment: Great! thanks for clearing that up. the alternative has has worked, ill read up on .NET corefx, thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing your entire file's content to the string representation of a collections of words. You need to compare each individual word found in the file content to your abbreviated list. One way you could do the comparison is to split the file content into individual words and then look those up individually against your abbreviated list.

```
string[] fileWords = FC.Split(Separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

bool hasMatch = false;
for(string fileWord : fileWords)
{
    if(Abbreviated.Contains(fileWord))
    {
        hasMatch = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (hasMatch)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Match found");

}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Match");
}
```

I would recommend switching your abbreviated collection to a HashSet or a Dictionary that also includes your matching expanded text for the abbreviation. Also, there are probably alternate ways to do the search you are looking for with regex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure on what some of your variables are so this may be slightly different to what you have, but gives the same functionality.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> abbreviated = new List<string>();
            List<string> expanded = new List<string>();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("textwords.csv");
            string TxtWrd = "";
            while ((TxtWrd = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("line: " + TxtWrd);
                string[] Words = TxtWrd.Split(new char[] { ',' } , StringSplitOptions.None);
                abbreviated.Add(Words[0]);
                expanded.Add(Words[1]);
            }

            if (abbreviated.Contains("wuu2"))
            {
                //show message box
            } else
            {
                //don't
            }

        }
```

As mentioned in one of the comments, a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) might be better suited for this.

This assumes that the data in your file is in the following format, with a new set on each line.

> wuu2,what are you up to

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is check if a text file contains words in your list, you can read the entire contents of the file into a string (instead of line by line), split the string on your separators, and then check if the intersection of the words in the text file and your list of words has any items:

```
// Get the "separators" into a list
var wordsFile = @"c:\public\temp\textWords.csv"; // (@"C:\textwords.csv");
var separators = File.ReadAllText(wordsFile).Split(',');

// Get the words of the file into a list (add more delimeters as necessary)
var txtFile = @"c:\public\temp\temp.txt";
var allWords = File.ReadAllText(txtFile).Split(new[] {' ', '.', ',', ';', ':', '\r', '\n'});

// Get the intersection of the file words and the separator words
var commonWords = allWords.Intersect(separators).ToList().Distinct();

if (commonWords.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("The text file contains the following matching words:");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", commonWords));
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("The file did not contain any matching words.");
}

Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey();
```